# Order by not working properly CakePHP 2.4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have a function in my controller called view and the code is give below :

```
$conditions =   array(
                            'OR'=>array(
                                        'User.id'=>$this->Auth->user("id"),
                                        'Sharing.user_id' => $this->Auth->user("id"),
                                        )
                        );
    $joins      =   array(
                         array('table' => 'clists_sharings',
                                'alias' => 'Sharing',
                                'type' => 'LEFT',
                                'conditions' => array(
                                'Sharing.user_id' => $this->Auth->user("id"),
                                'Sharing.clist_id = Clist.id'
                            )
                        ),
                        array('table' => 'clists_tags',
                                'alias' => 'Tag',
                                'type' => 'LEFT',
                                'conditions' => array(
                                'Tag.clist_id = Clist.id'
                               )
                        ),
                        array('table' => 'clist_orders',
                                'alias' => 'DisplayOrder',
                                'type' => 'LEFT',
                                'conditions' => array(
                                'DisplayOrder.clist_id = Clist.id',
                                'DisplayOrder.user_id' => $this->Auth->user("id")
                               )
                        )
                    );
    $this->Paginator->settings = array(
                                        'conditions' => $conditions,
                                        'limit' => 15,
                                        'joins' => $joins,
                                        'recursive'=>1,
                                        'order'=>array("DisplayOrder.display_order"=>"ASC"),
                                        'group'=>'Clist.id'
                                    );

    $lists  =   $this->Paginator->paginate( 'Clist' );

    $this->set('lists', $lists);
```

I have the sql log for this request :

```
SELECT `Clist`.`id`, `Clist`.`user_id`, `Clist`.`title`, `Clist`.`list_type`, `Clist`.`archived`, `Clist`.`created`, `Clist`.`modified`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`full_name`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`role_id`, `User`.`is_activated`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified`, `User`.`reset`, `User`.`reset_hash` FROM `conduit`.`dll_clists` AS `Clist` LEFT JOIN `conduit`.`dll_clists_sharings` AS `Sharing` ON (`Sharing`.`user_id` = '1' AND `Sharing`.`clist_id` = `Clist`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `conduit`.`dll_clists_tags` AS `Tag` ON (`Tag`.`clist_id` = `Clist`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `conduit`.`dll_clist_orders` AS `DisplayOrder` ON (`DisplayOrder`.`clist_id` = `Clist`.`id` AND `DisplayOrder`.`user_id` = '1') LEFT JOIN `conduit`.`dll_users` AS `User` ON (`Clist`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE ((`User`.`id` = 1) OR (`Sharing`.`user_id` = '1')) GROUP BY `Clist`.`id` LIMIT 15
```

The order by clause is missing here. Anyone can point out what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Try all in one line: `'order' => array("DisplayOrder.display_order ASC")`

Comment: Tried but not working..

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested, but you may need to set the order within a key of the model name in the settings array.

```
   $this->Paginator->settings = array(
          'conditions' => $conditions,
          'limit' => 15,
          'joins' => $joins,
          'recursive'=>1,
          'DisplayOrder' => array(
              'order'=>array("display_order"=>"ASC"),                  
           ),
          'group'=>'Clist.id'
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you missed something on how to use CakePHP.

It seems that you didn't use the 'belongsTo', 'hasMany' ... options available for models. It will allow you to do all this job for you.

Check here for more details:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Regarding your problem, once you did a proper model for the User table, you just need to do something like:

```
    $hasOne = array(
    'DisplayOrder' => array(
        'className' => 'DisplayOrder',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'order' => 'DisplayOrder.display_order ASC'
    ),
```